# I want to scrape content or data from dynamic web page using php?

Tags: php

Is it possible to scrape content or data from dynamic web page? If it is possible please attach PHP code. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please add here.

Comment: try to do your homework yourself .

Comment: you want to show the php code on browser ?

Comment: Thank you guys, But I have done it...

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
```

$html = file_get_contents("http://yellowpages.sulekha.com/chennai/lakshmi-air-system-virugambakkam-chennai_contact-address");

preg_match_all(
    '/ (.*?)</p>/s',
    $html,
    $posts,
    PREG_SET_ORDER // formats data into an array of posts
);
print_r($posts[0][1]);
echo "

" . count($posts) . " posts found

";

Comment: You should add your code in question. Also, using Ctrl+K to wrap your PHP code.